# Behind of or in front of?

Tags: word-usage

We daily use terms like "I was sitting in front of the television" and "Spent the all day behind the computer".

What is the most appropriate term to use and why is it that *people sit in front of the television* and will say they *sat behind the computer*? Which one is more appropriate to use? Does it depend? Why?

Comment: The question is:  Are you leading the computer, or is the computer leading you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think just as many people would say "sitting in **front** of a computer".

But you would say I was "stuck **behind** a book all day", because the book is hiding you.

Comment: So that would imply that the usage *sat behind the computer* is only correct if the computer covers or hides part of the person using it?

Comment: @BrunoPereira - yes, you do say "working behind a desk"

Comment: Spending time *behind a computer* is correct if you're a technician connecting and/or disconnecting cables, or performing other maintenance activities, but it seems unlikely that a skilled practitioner would need to spend a whole day on a single computer.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the object of the preposition.  Each object, by convention, has a front and a back and if one is positioned next to the object's front, then one is *in front* of the object.  Likewise if one is positioned next to the object's back, then one is *behind* the object.

The front of a television is the screen, and therefore when watches television one is in front of it.  A TV repairman might sit behind it.

A desk is an interesting thing, though, because the front and back of a desk sometimes varies with the placement in the room and the type of desk.  The term, "behind a desk" is typically used when the desk is out in the open and comes between the person sitting at the desk and a person entering the room so that from the visitor's perspective the person is sitting behind the desk. Desks designed for this kind of placement usually have ornate "fronts" as opposed to desks designed to go up against a wall that have simple plywood or cardboard panels on the back.  However when the desk is pushed up against a wall one typically just speaks of sitting *at* the desk rather than *in front of* or *behind* it.

Answer (score 0):

The parallel to *behind* is *before*, and no one would say "before of" (or "beside", "below" or "beneath of") something.  Conversely, we would say "in the rear of" or "at the side of". Since *before* is so closely associated with time, "in front of" is likely used for clarity.

Comment: Um, “in the rear of”?

Answer (score 0):

Some people say "in back of the sofa".  The sofa and the computer each has a front and a back, in which something can be.  That "something" can be by the sofa's back (in back of the sofa) or by the television's front (in front of the television).

When you are behind something, in many (but not all) cases you are not only near its back, you are also at least partially hidden by it.

I usually don't say I am behind the computer; I say I am in front of the computer.  The computer is facing me.